# The render do not render to the template

Tags: python, django

In the admin index page I bind a id to a button, and use jquery ajax to request a logout event:

```
$("#logout").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url:'/logout/',
        type:'POST'

    })
})
```

And in the frontend/views.py:

```
def logout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.session['username'] = None
        request.session['is_login'] = False
        import app_admin.views as app_admin_views
        app_admin_views.conn = None # clean the connection
        print ('before logout')
        return render(request,'frontend/login.html')
```

In the  Terminal have printed the 'before logout', but the page do not render to the `frontend/login.html`, and I also tried use redirect, all failure.

Comment: try `return render(request, "frontend/login.html", {})`

Comment: @N.Ivanov Not work too.

Comment: are you sure that the template name and directory match, and exist? And also it should display something in the terminal after the `before logout` message. Also what do you get in your browser? Did you check your browser console?

Comment: yes, quite sure.

Comment: You're making an AJAX request to your backend. You need to either have a callback in your client to handle response from the backend or go to the logout location. Otherwise, I don't see why logout is a HTTP POST request here

Comment: Totally unrelated but this : `import app_admin.views as app_admin_views;
        app_admin_views.conn = None # clean the connection` is _garanteed_ to break as soon as you have multiple users, and even more when you have multiple processes running your project.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers What do you mean, my friend? How to do with that?

Comment: In Python a module is technically a singleton that lives from the whole life of the process (or at least from the very first import til the end of the process). Since Django is typically served using parallel long-running processes, this means that 1. the same process will serve many clients and 2. the same client can be served by any of the process (each successive request might be served by any of the processes - the first available one actually).

Comment: So you end up with user A data stored as `yourmod.var` in process 1, then on the following request user A will be served by process 2 which has it's own distinct copy of `yourmod.var`, which might be empty or might be data from user B. In the meantime user B's next request is served by process1, and then user B gets user A's `yourmod.var` data.

Comment: To make a long story short: __never__ store "session" data in a process memory space. Either store them in the database or as proper session using the session framework.

Comment: As a side note: django comes with a builtin user/auth framework and a session farmework that correctly handles all of those problems, are stable, secure and well tested, and are easily customozable / extensible, so don't reinvent the proverbial squared wheel and learn to use the provided tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In logout view function, return a redirect

```
return redirect('login-or-something')
```

In javascript AJAX request handle the redirect response,

```
function handleSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

  location.href = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Location');
}

function handleError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(errorThrown); // send to some error log collectors
}


$.ajax({
    url:'/logout/',
    type:'POST'
    success: handleSuccess,
    error: handleErr
});
```

Comment: do you mean logout use GET is better?